# Indicator on different timeframe than chart

Tags: pine-script

I've been struggling to use a indicator, for example the awesome oscillator, on a different timeframe than what the chart is in. This is for a strategy in Pinescript.

I can't seem to get the right information to code a working program and get even close to using the indicator on a different timeframe.

This is what I've tried, but can't figure out how to use the standard AO indicator.

```
fastAo = input(12, minval=1, title="Fast AO")
slowAo = input(57, minval=1, title="Slow AO")

awesome = sma(hl2,fastAo) - sma(hl2,slowAo)
```

But now I have to be able to use this on a different tf than the chart is in.

I've read some other posts about the security function, but I can't seem to get the AO build-in indicator to work.

```
atr14 = atr(14)
atr1hour = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", atr14)
```

I appericiate all the help!

Daan

```
fastAo = input(12, minval=1, title="Fast AO")
slowAo = input(57, minval=1, title="Slow AO")

awesome = sma(hl2,fastAo) - sma(hl2,slowAo)
```

But that is mainly the normal AO. I want to use the AO on a different timeframe than the one that the chart is currently in.

Answer (score 0):

to get the awesome indicator in another timeframe, use :

```
awesome = sma(hl2,fastAo) - sma(hl2,slowAo)
1hour = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", awesome)
```